# Como importar fontes localmente no css?

Tags: css, css-font-face

Estou desenvolvendo um site e estou tendo dificuldades na questão das fontes.

Localmente elas aparecem, fiz o upload para o servidor dos meus arquivos o site aparece normalmente, porém **só as fontes** não aparecem, tentei fazer o @font-face mais não deu certo.

Como eu importo uma fonte local? É possível?

Comment: Podes por favor mostrar como importas as fontes; ou seja, podes colocar o html ou css onde importas as fontes

Comment: Aparece algum erro no Console do DevTools? Se sim qual?

Comment: Eu não estava sabendo utilizar o @font-face por isso postei aqui, vou tentar a solução proposta nos comentários abaixo assim que chegar em casa e torno a responder.

Answer (score 2):

Usar o `@font-face` do CSS é uma boa alternativa. Supondo que seu projeto tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
site/
├── css/
│   └── styles.css
├─── fonts/
│   ├── Oxygen-Regular.eot
│   ├── Oxygen-Regular.svg
│   ├── Oxygen-Regular.ttf
│   ├── Oxygen-Regular.woff
│   └── Oxygen-Regular.woff2
└── index.html
```

Para ter uma boa compatibilidade com os navegadores atuais, você vai precisar ter pelo menos os arquivos `.woff2` e `.woff` da sua fonte (estou usando como exemplo a fonte [Oxygen](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oxygen)). Copie-os para a pasta `fonts` e no seu arquivo `styles.css`, faça:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    src: url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Depois disto, basta atribuir a fonte em algum elemento, por exemplo ao `body`:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}
```

Para o máximo de compatibilidade, incluindo navegadores um pouco mais antigos, você vai precisar dos arquivos `.eot`, `.woff`, `.woff2`, `.ttf` e `.svg` da sua fonte. Daí ficaria assim:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    src: url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.svg#oxygen') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado tentarei utilizar a sua solução.

Comment: devo ter colocado algo errado se poder conferir agradeceria, não funcionou, copie e cole os links para entender melhor.

Comment: https://ibb.co/w7ZVPFC estrutura do servidor
https://ibb.co/1Zc7Vvc  como coloquei o código
https://ibb.co/6vW7HMS como ficou e como quero

Comment: Você precisa usar `../` e não `./`, além disto, faltou atualizar o nome da fonte para o formato `.svg` na segunda imagem. Você também precisa atribuir a fonte aos elementos que você deseja, como fiz acima para o `body`.